# Strange behaviour on calender control (ToolTip)

Tags: asp.net, html, calendar

I add Tooltips to a ASP.NET calendar control by code:

```
string newToolTip = string.Format(@"<div class='tooltip'><div class='toolHead'>{0}</div><div class='toolDate'>{1}-{2}</div></div>",sEvent.Title, sEvent.FromDate, sEvent.ToDate);
e.Cell.ToolTip = newToolTip;
e.Cell.Attributes.Add("OnClick", string.Format("javascript:__doPostBack('Karl Ender','{0}')", sEvent.Title));
```

Where "e" is a DayRenderEventArgs :

```
Calendar.DayRender += new DayRenderEventHandler(SpecialDayRender);
```

At the first Load of the page everything works fine, resulting in the following (correct) html-code:

```
<td title="" class="calendarcell" align="center" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('Karl Ender','Hallo Welt')" style="color:White;background-color:Silver;width:14%;">7<div class="tooltip"><div class="toolHead">Hallo Welt</div><div class="toolDate">11/7/2012-5/9/2013</div></div></td>
```

When I change the month (or do another partial Postback) in the Calendar Control suddenly the Html-Code gets dizzy:

```
<td title="&lt;div class='tooltip'&gt;&lt;div class='toolHead'&gt;Hallo Welt&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class='toolDate'&gt;11/7/2012-5/9/2013&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;" class="calendarcell" align="center" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('Karl Ender','Hallo Welt')" style="color:White;background-color:Silver;width:14%;">7</td>
```

So, the Tooltip gets rendered as a "Title"-Attribute of that Cell

Any clue?

(The calendar is within an updatePanel)

When debugging the code, the Title-Attribute of a cell is never filled with that strange content

Comment: what happens if the code is within a `if(!Page.isPostBack)`

Comment: Is sEvent the id of your Calendar control?Are you using the AJAX control toolkit?

Comment: @Flakes nothing will be rendered then.

Comment: @Deni sEvent is just a simple object with string properties. The Container is within an ASP:UpdatePanel. No other Ajax-Magic there